# How to present views one at a time in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, view, swiftui

I am looking to make a quiz app using SwiftUI. I have now designed all of the views, but I am having trouble displaying the questions correctly.
I have a home view which for now just has a button that should display a questionView (has only one question) in order and one at a time.
I am using a ForEach to step through each question in a questions array and display a questionView with that specific question, but the problem is that the ForEach displays every question at the same time instead of waiting for the question to be submitted.
How can communicate with the ForEach (or any other function) to tell it when to start and stop showing questionViews.

```
struct Home: View {
    @State var presentQuestionView: Bool = false
    @StateObject var questionViewModel: QuestionViewModel = QuestionViewModel()
    @State var isCompleted = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
   
            Text("Guess Players")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                
                .onTapGesture {
                        presentQuestionView.toggle()
                }
            
            Spacer()
                
        }
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentQuestionView, content: {
            ForEach(questionViewModel.questions.indices) { index in

                QuestionView(question: questionViewModel.questions[index], presentQuestionView: $presentQuestionView, progressWidth: questionViewModel.progress(currentIndex: index) )
                    
                      .offset(x: questionViewModel.currentQuestion().isCompleted ? 1000 : 0)
                      .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: questionViewModel.currentQuestion().isCompleted ? 1000 : 0))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

when the button is clicked, I want the ForEach statement to present the QuestionView one at a time.

Here is my QuestionView

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var question: Question
    @Binding var presentQuestionView: Bool
    var progressWidth: CGFloat
    @State var isSubmitted = false
    @State var buttonText = "Submit"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center), content: {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.7))
                    .frame(height: 6)
                
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: progressWidth, height: 6)
            })
            
            Text("Guess The Player!")
                .font(.system(size: 38))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                .padding(.top)
            Text("Career Averages: ")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 8)
            
            Text("Points Per Game: \(question.answer.stats!.pointsPerGame)")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            
            Text("Assists Per Game: \(question.answer.stats!.assistsPerGame)")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            
            Text("Rebounds Per Game: \(question.answer.stats!.reboundsPerGame)")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 2), spacing: 25, content: {
                Player_Cards(question: question, isSubmitted: $isSubmitted)
            })
            .padding()
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Button(action: {
                if isSubmitted == false {
                    //update the score
                    if question.isCorrect() {

                    } else {

                    }
                    //update the view to show the correct answer
                    isSubmitted.toggle()
                    buttonText = "Next Question"
                } else {
                    //Go into the next question
                }
                
            }, label: {
                Text(buttonText)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            })
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05).ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
```

This is what currently happens when I run this project
[image: The views are stacked on top of each other instead of showing one at a time until the submit button is clicked.]

Comment: That is what the ForEach does. It loops through the Array and runs the code inside the {} for each instance. What you want to do is have some sort of @State variable that keeps track of which # question you are on and keys it in to the array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand the concept behind the @State var, but how would I call the next view?

Comment: Your ViewModel is already an `@StateObject` which is an array. Therefore, if you have a variable declared as `@State var questionNumber = 0` you would pull the question up as `questionViewModel.questions[questionNumber]` And completely remove the ForEach.